# How to force release of mouse capture while moving a form in C#?

Tags: c#, forms, drag-and-drop, mouse, capture

C# .NET 4.0 WinForms

I have an unusual situation with form dragging.  I need the following behavior:

- When the user clicks on the Windows Title Bar of a Form and drags it around the screen, everything responds normally.
- If the user presses and holds the Ctrl Key while dragging the Form by the Windows Title Bar, the Window is dropped and hidden, a special drag token is created ( a different mini Form ), and the drag token is captured and moved with the mouse instead.  The drag token is used with an elaborate docking system and provides feedback about the docking options and selected drop target.

Question:

How can I programmatically release the mouse capture of a Form mid drag if the Ctrl Key is pressed, so that I can hide it and initiate capture of a different Form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  The User32 library has a ReleaseCapture method that will cause the mouse to let go of any Forms that are currently being dragged.

The example below shows how to cancel the Form drag when the user presses the Ctrl key:

```
 public static class User32_DLL
{
    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();
}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.EnableNotifyMessage, true);
    }


    protected override void OnNotifyMessage(Message m)
    {
        const int WM_MOVING = 0x0216;

        if (m.Msg == WM_MOVING)
        {
            if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
            {
                User32_DLL.ReleaseCapture();
            }
        }
        base.OnNotifyMessage(m);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First consider do you need to reinvent the wheel. There are several docking [libraries](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/) out [there](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18812/WPF-Docking-Library).

And then if you still can't resist the urge you can always drop the standard window frame and draw your own and handle the window dragging events in a custom manner:

```
if (Keyboard.CTRL){
  CustomDrag();
} else {
  this.DragMove(); //Window.DragMove() calls the OS to start dragging the window
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Sten.  I hadn't thought of abandoning the Window Frame and drawing my own, that is an interesting idea.  I am not quite ready to go that far yet unless it is the only option.  I will keep that as a backup plan.  As for the docking libraries, I was using Krypton, but there were too many special cases that I needed to entertain that Krypton wouldn't support, so I built a custom methodology that works much better for my application.  There should be a way to terminate a Window drag.  Any ideas ?